# How to check Zend_Session expiration after using Zend_Session::rememberMe

Tags: zend-framework, session

I use `Zend_Session::rememberMe(60*60*24*90);` to make the session of a logged-in user to last for 90 days.

I've read the Zend_Session documentation but didn't find any method to check that this expiration is actually set somewhere.

I cannot check the browser cookie, at least directly, as the webpage is embedded within an Adobe Air widget.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want it for debugging purpose use:

```
var_dump($_SESSION['__ZF']);
```

you can see all of the values stored in zend session including rememberme 's expiration.

Comment: It says: `PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  __ZF`